# Ubuntu 12.10 won't install with USB pendrive, incorrect screen resolution

Tags: 12.10, resolution, screen

I downloaded 12.10 and used the Universal USB software to create the pendrive.  My computer boots up fine with the pendrive, but when it comes to the options screen for the installation, I get 5 or more screens displayed on my screen.  I can't see the bottom of the screen to select which options I want.  I'm not sure if it's my video card, or if Ubuntu isn't recognizing my screen resolution correctly.

Comment: So what is your exact question?

Comment: How do I get the Ubuntu installation to display correctly on my screen?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, create the bootable USB with [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)
boot into live-mode and try to change the screen resultion to something that fits your monitor, hope this helps!

Comment: I found a fix with the software you recommended.  I had to run Ubuntu without installing and go to the display options from there and change my screen resolution.  The resolution detected upon startup was not the correct resolution for my display.

Comment: I´m glad that my anwser pointed you to the right direction, probably you could execpt it as answer, would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

I have a HP Pavilion dv6000 and I did the same to install it from a Pen Drive but I got the "mixed screens" and I was unable to get them right.

I tried several things that did not work which I want to share as well so you dont do them:

1. I tried making the boot usb drive with UNetbootin but I found no way to change the resolution or vga mode when making it.
2. I tried modifying the .cfg files from the boot section adding "vga=640x460" or vga=768 or 771 as those are basic resolutions but it seems the ubuntu 12.10 works with grab2 that doesnt use that anymore.
3. I tried installing a 12.04 version with no success.
4. I tried editing changing the resolution in this weird mode but it is impossibe

And I finally did the following:

When booting you see an image in the middle and bottom of the screen and I hit enter
you enter configuration mode before running or installing.

Press F6 and move down to **nomodeset-** press Space and selects. then Esc and then go to run or installed.

It worked. Now I have to get the right driver for the nvidia board.